# Javascript unable to find any part of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, typo3

I have noticed an interesting issue on a website that I am helping a friend with. When I am on the homepage I can use javascript/jQuery to access the DOM as expected and everything works fine. If I use the console and type console.log($('html')); it returns the html object from the site as expected.

However, if I do this exact same thing on any page other than the index, it returns null. The source of the page appears to be the same and I can see all the elements there, but javascript itself does not seem to be aware of them.

The site is built using the Typo3 CMS, if that could be part of it.

Does anybody have any experience with this? Or is there any way to tell javascript to re-read the DOM after the full page load?

**EDIT** Somebody asked for a link to the site so here it is: http://www.stinglonline.de/

Comment: `$()` is provided by jquery. is it being loaded on those other pages? if it's only loaded by the homepage, then that explains why the subpages aren't working for this.

Comment: Can you give us a link? The dom is an object so there is no need to "re-read" it as it is a referenced object.

Comment: I posted the link above but you can find the site [here](http://www.stinglonline.de/) as well

Comment: Just ran the following in the console and got a one-element array containing the body, as expected: $('body');

Comment: @lyyons i got the behavior they describe. Enter `$()` on http://www.stinglonline.de/top-menue/home.html and you get an empty array. Entry `$()` on http://www.stinglonline.de/haupt-menue/stingl-gmbh/profil.html and you get undefined.

Comment: Lyyons, did you get that on the index or on another page? I get the body on index, but say I go to the Produkte page, it returns Null

Comment: Try removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` since this is not an xml file, it is an html file. Also you can simplify `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` to `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Ah, got it. Try jQuery('body'), which seems to work on all pages.

Comment: @LoganMurphy While I see the merit of removing the <?xml> tag, I'm not sure I understand how that would fix this particular issue because the tag exists on the index as well, where javascript works.

Comment: @lyyons You are a life saver! Now... any idea why it $ doesn't work? It was my understanding that $ == jQuery...

Comment: Yep, unless there's a conflict between it and something else. @scrappedcola has the correct answer below: There's conflict between jQuery and prototype, so you should set up jQuery.noConflict. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conflict between jquery and prototype.
Add something along the lines of `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` and then update your jquery on that page to use the new `$j` variable such `$j("html")` and it should work for you. See: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

I tested this, in console, on http://www.stinglonline.de/haupt-menue/stingl-gmbh/profil.html.

Alternatively you can just use `jQuery` instead of the `$`, whichever works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like only the home page is running jQuery.</strike>
If you use native Javascript to select from the DOM it works just fine.

Give it a try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html');
```

That does the same thing in Javascript that $('html'); does in jQuery.
There are a few [Notes and things to consider](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) When using this native Javascript method.

I find jQuery very useful, but without a proper understanding of native Javascript it becomes a crutch.

**EDIT**
[scrappedcola's Answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548250/3612850) I missed the jQuery  tag in the code when I looked.

Comment: All the pages on the site are running jQuery. Try running jQuery('div') or console.dir'ing jQuery.

Comment: @lyyons Thank you for pointing that out. I did a quick search through the markup and didn't see jQuery included in a <script> tag. I must have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like the `$` is part of the jquery library on http://www.stinglonline.de/top-menue/home.html

But the `$` is part of the Prototype library on every other page.

You do not have this issue on the homepage because you do not use prototype there.

You should declare your prototype library BEFORE you declare you jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

In the homepage, type $ in console(Chrome) as blow. It use jquery.
So $('html') return document.getElementsByTagName('html').

```
>$
function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}   jquery.js?1399526417:2
```

in other pages, type $ in console(Chrome) as blow. It use prototype.
So $('html') return document.getElementById('html'), 
$('skiplinks') return document.getElementById('skiplinks').

```
>$
function $(b){
    if(arguments.length>1){
        for(var a=0,d=[],c=arguments.length;a<c;a++){
            d.push($(arguments[a]))
        }
        return d
    }
    if(Object.isString(b)){
        b=document.getElementById(b)
    }
    return Element.extend(b)
} 
prototype.1.7.0.yui.js:1

$('skiplinks')
<ul id=​"skiplinks">​…​</ul>​
```